# Не отображается JS на страницах сайта

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

Вывожу любой код JS в блоке, но он не отображается на сайте. Есть подозрение, что проблема в JQuery, но явных ошибок с помощью FireBug не нашел.

Для примера, страница [сайта](https://finansanswer.ru/banki/mikrokreditnye-organizacii/zajmy-vivus/), блок "Партнеры".

Answer (score 0):

Загляните в консоль. У вас js падает с ошибкой `adsplacerTrackIframeClick is not defined`, после чего уже никакой код не выполняется.

Comment: К сожалению не видел данную ошибку. Есть какое то решение

Comment: Решение в том, чтобы исправлять эту ошибку. Править или отключать код, который ее вызывает. Но этовсе тема отдельного вопроса.

Comment: Если не трудно можно скрин ошибки, я у себя ее воспроизвести не могу. Спасибо!

Comment: Сегодня я уже не вижу эту ошибку в консоли. Вчера была.

Comment: Тогда получается проблема не в этом.

Comment: Сейчас уже не в этом, да. У вас там goole ads запущен. Его код сработал - сформировано масса элементов и iframe http://take.ms/laRmi . Только вот внутри iframe пусто - так причина уже в настройках этого ads. Вопрос совсем не так поставлен. Никаких проблем в jQuery нет.